# visual studio react image path cannot reach

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So i have a visual studio project created with react.js.

I am trying to link to an image dynamically, but failing. This is the code I am trying:

At the top im setting a variable for the first part of the path:

```
this.LogoPath = '../images/'
```

And then im dynamically grabbing the name of the image from an api call.

```
this.setState({ imageNamePath: this.state.location.imageName })
```

And then im concatinating them:

```
{`${this.LogoPath}${this.state.location.imageName}`}
```

In the console, im getting:

```
img src='../images/the-images-name-here.png'
```

So it seems to be working, but it is not. I get no errors, and I have broken images. My best guess is that react is changing the images to something like:

image-name-here.6a131799.png

Surely someone has run across this before, but my google search pulled up little help.

So how do i get the images to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is a smart tool. One of it's strength is the trash code/files elimination from the bundle.

That means that if a file is not imported using `import myFile from '../myPath/myFile.jpg';` or require('../myPath/myFile.jpg');` it won't be a part of the final bundle.

In your case you're not importing the file. You're creating a string variable instead which means nothing to webpack.

There are different options that could work in your case:

**Option 1:** Pre-import all images and map them in an object:

```
import React, {Component} from  'react';
import image1 from '../assets/image1.png';
import image2 from '../assets/image2.png';
import image3 from '../assets/image3.png';

const imageTypes = {
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageType: 'image1'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <img src={imageTypes[this.state.imageType]} />
    )
  }
}
```

**Option 2:** Not recommended - Use require to dynamically import files (webpack configurations might be needed in order to include all possible required images in the production bundle):

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: 'file1.png'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <img src={require(`./assets/${this.state.image}`)} />
    )
  }
}
```

**Option 3:** Send the image blob (in base64) from the API.

I suggest you to use the **Option 1** or **Option 3**, based on your requirements, such as: how often will be images be changed/added/removed. It's not normal to import files dynamically from ReactJS bundle and you might end up having a non-existing image in your project requested by the data coming from an external source.

For **Option 2** you also might have some problems configuring the webpack in order to include in the bundle all the images that you'll probably need to render, even though they are not imported (hardcoded) somewhere in the JS files. Keep in mind that the React Application in production ends up being a collection of static files. You'll need to treat them as follows.

Comment: All good stuff, thank you. However, because im mapping through the api call array in the render, each image could be different based on an id they each have. So i need to do an if statement to figure out which. I suppose thats a different question though.